# The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core

I have an authentication microservice and I want to keep it running in a container. When I run the

```
docker compose up
```

on the approval server it works fine, when I run it on the production server I get the following error

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached, or the per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors has been reached.
```

How to solve ?

Answer (score 1):

to inscrease this limit to 256:

```sh
echo 256| sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

To increase this limit even after a reboot use:

```sh
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=256| sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: did not work for my case.

Comment: Looks like it might also need a bump of [fs.inotify.max_user_instances](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/19814#issuecomment-1477564132)